# Composite primary key, Google app engine (django)

Tags: django, google-app-engine, uniqueidentifier, composite-primary-key, hash-function

I use django nonrel/djangoappengine on google app engine. It is not possible to specify composite primary keys directly. However it should be possible to emulate this behaviour. I am wondering about what is the best approach.

**Problem**

Conside the following datamodel

```
class AccumuatedSales(models.Model):
    salesman = models.ForeignKey(Salesman)
    year = models.Postiveinteger()
    totalSales = models.PositiveInteger()
```

I want (salesman, year) to be treated as a primary key. That is, if I do

```
asby1 = AccumulatedSales(salesman='Joe', year=2010, totalSales=100)
asby1.save()
asby2 = AccumulatedSales(salesman='Joe', year=2010, totalSales=200)
asby2.save()
```

The 'table' AccumulatedSales should contain *one* row. So the second save overwrites the first.

**Possible Solution**

```
class AccumuatedSales(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(primary_key=True,, default=None, editable=False)
    salesman = models.ForeignKey(Salesman)
    year = models.Postiveinteger()
    totalSales = models.PositiveInteger()

    def save(self):
        self.key = someHashFunction(self.salesman_id, self.year)
        super(AccumulatedSales, self).save()
```

**Questions**

- is this approach good or "the right one"?
- What is the best datatype for the field key? Personally I would like to have som 128-bit  field, but that is not available to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a pretty good solution.