# Creating a hashed Primary Key when composite key is not permitted

Tags: sql, django, schema, hashtable, composite-primary-key

My question is about the solution seen in the post below... I think that is is a fantastic idea. Especially since Django has had the composite primary key issue for years. To me this is a great workaround given that you know the items in advance. However, this seems to have little feedback given that so many people have looked into composite keys in django. Can someone please point out the downside to this approach?

I feel that as long as the salesperson has a unique ID you shouldn't have any hash collisions correct? even if the years overlap. Additionally as long as you provide an index on the salesperson column you can perform fast select statements as this simulates the index automatically placed on a primary key.

However, I am clearly only seeing the positive, is there a danger with using this approach.

Thank you for any info.

[Composite primary key, Google app engine (django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375156/composite-primary-key-google-app-engine-django/15853869#15853869)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing a hash of two columns as the primary key is not very readable.  You could consider an alternative.  For example, for salesman and year, you could use the name of the salesman, then underscore, then year as the primary key:

```
ID         Salesman    Year    ...
Joe_2011   Joe         2011    ...
```

This is a lot easier to debug than storing a hash.

However, the hash is a perfectly safe and common technique, if that is what you prefer.

Comment: Great thank you. This does make a lot of sense. Actually now in retrospect this method seems a safer approach. In theory if you were to use a Hash function of the addition of two numbers you may run into issues if the sum of different combinations of items produced the same value. i.e. salesperson 12 year 2000 and salesperson 6 and year 2006. This could obviously be avoided by a smarter hashing function but just as a base case. Do you agree?

Comment: In practice a hash collision is unlikely (once per universe liftetime :))  But to be entirely sure, you have to compare the content of the retrieved row.

Comment: Agreed hash collisions on a table are rare. But in this base case wouldn't they be common. (I know this is slightly off topic now, but relates to the safety of the proposed method in case anyone wants to use it later)

if say salesmanId=12 and year 2000 then in the proposed solution assume a Md5 hash. Hash((2000+12)) --> Hash(2012)

if say salesmanId=6 and year 2006 then in the proposed solution assume a Md5 hash. Hash((2006+6)) --> Hash(2012) 

these two hash codes would be equal if running on the same system implementation of GetHashcode. 

Your Solution of 12_2000 and 6_2006 seems safer?

Comment: A hash should be done on a string, not on an integer! So `2000+12` would give a different hash than `2006+6`

Comment: Ah agreed sorry I was starting to think too abstractly. Agreed should be a string hash. I was forgetting about how override hash functions worked in some languages. Thanks again for the solution. Very clean.

Comment: The approach in the OP presents a delimiter collision risk. For example `salesman=O'hara` would result in an ID with a non-alphanumeric character. Using a hash function avoids this risk.